# Re directing to another page Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have am trying to re direct the page to another route with parameter
like this passing id as a parameter.

```
 $location.path('/api/po/'+id);
```

What is the proper way to re direct to another page using router and parameter? My module, controller etc all are working fine. Just having problem re directing.
Thaks

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: If i remove the id i get re directed fine if i add id it doesnt go. I tink the problem is the syntax doesn't look right

Comment: show your $routeProvider configuration. Does id have value?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to me is the better way to build a function that move you application from a view to another one. It's really easy to use and very rich of useful method.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Install ui-router using bower
2. Include angular-ui-router.js in your index.html
3. Add 'ui.router' to your main module's list of dependencies
4. Add a ui-view directive to the some  in your html
5. Set up your states in the module config, following is an example how:

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])

```
  myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        templateUrl: "route1.html"
    })
    .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        templateUrl: "route2.html"
    })
})
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) in case of doubt.